# Let $ P_n(z) $ be a polynomial of degree $ n $ with leading coefficient $1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ P_n(z) $ be a polynomial of degree $ n $ with leading coefficient $1$. Show that if   $ max_{|z|\le1}|P_n (z)|\le M$, then $ max_{|z|\le1}|P'_n (z)|\le enM$.

It's hard to deal with $e$. I have tried  using $e=\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n$ and  Cauchy integral formula but failed. Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is so called Bernstein inequality and it holds with const 1, that is $$max|P^{'}(z)| <= nM$$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_(polynomials)#Bernstein's_inequality